# Plotly express title styling

Tags: python, pie-chart, plotly-python

I have been struggling for several hours to style my pie chart title. In essence, I would like to increase the font size and make it bold. Neither from the object parameter nor the `update_layout` I found the proper way to handle this.

Is there also any way to increase the size of the labels and remove the legend?

Thanks a lot for your support!

Here is my code :

```
pie_chart = px.pie(
    data_frame=ca_sum_df,
    values='Last month sales',
    names='Commercial network',
    color='Commercial network',
    #color_discrete_sequence=["red","green"],
    color_discrete_map={'VIP customers':"#d28c00","Standard Retail Partner":'#d9d9d9'},
    hover_data=['Commercial network','Last month sales'],
    title="TURNOVER SPLIT-DOWN",
    template='ggplot2',
    width=800,
    height=600,
    hole=0.5

)
pie_chart.update_layout(
    # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
    annotations=[dict(text=val_ca_sum, x=0.50, y=0.5, font_size=30, showarrow=False)],
    font=dict(size=25)
)

pie_chart.write_image("images/Page1_TurnoverSplitDown.png")
```

Answer (score 5):

The font size can be changed with

```
pie_chart.update_layout(title={'font': {'size': 50}})
```

To make the title bold, use HTML syntax `<b></b>`:

```
pie_chart.update_layout(title={'text': '<b>TURNOVER SPLIT-DOWN</b>'})
```

The size of the labels can be changed with

```
pie_chart.update_layout(font={'size': 30})
```

and the legend can be removed with

```
pie_chart.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

You can combine all modifications into one call by writing:

```
pie_chart.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    font={'size': 30},
    title={'text': '<b>TURNOVER SPLIT-DOWN</b>', 'font': {'size': 50}}
)
```

Comment: This is absolutly fantastic. Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a title_font to change the size of the title.

```
fig.update_layout(title_font=dict(size=30))
```

https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-title-font